# Display the main report header in the sub report if the sub report opened in separated tab

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm facing a problem in crystal report: I want to display the main report header in the sub report if the sub report opened in separated tab.
Is there a formula or anything to do that.

I used :

Crystal Reports for Eclipse

Version: 2.0.1.r566

© 2008 Business Objects, an SAP company. All rights reserved.

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just add the main report header to the subreport's header?

As far as I'm aware, a subreport won't show the report header when it's a subreport, but will show the report header if it is run individually.

Comment: one question please: does crystal report hides the header of subreport when it displayed as a part of the main report and display the header automatically when open the subreport in a new tab individually